# Saving model to .h5 format using PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, h5py

I'm exporting model to `.h5` format using PyTorch like this.

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'model.h5')
```

But when I load this model.h5 in TensorFlow, I got this error.

```
File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 106, in h5py.h5f.open
OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)
```

I try both ways of saving models.

```
# 1.
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'model.h5')

# 2.
torch.save(model, 'model.h5')
```

In both ways, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: You might want to take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68577156/converting-from-pt-model-to-h5-model